# Assaigning values from 1-16 using an boolean array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, boolean

So I am trying to assign a value from 1-16 to variables x1-x16, based on 8 equations.
I tried using nested loops:

```
for(x1 = 1;x1 < 16;x1++)
{
    if(bValue[x1 - 1]) 
        bValue[x1 - 1] = false; 
    else 
        continue;
    //Loop for x2
    for(x2 = 1;x2 < 16;x2++)
    {
        ....Same format here....
    }
    bValue[x1 - 1] = true;
}
```

And later on come some tests like `if(((x1 * x2) - x3 - x4) == 56) {Proceed...}`

The problem is that no matter what I do, two variables can end up with the same value.
I tried while loops, do-while loops and boolean variables(none worked).

So, how can I edit the system so it 2 variables can't have the same value?

Comment: Did you initialized bValue array with true? Also, you´re only assinging 1-15 values to variables.

Comment: Yes, the size of array is 16 so I am assigning 1-16,but in boolean array I am using elements from nm.0-15,which is still 16 elements.

Comment: In `for(x1 = 1;x1 < 16;x1++)` `x1 < 16` says you will exit the loop when `x1` is 16. Either your logic is wrong or your description of what you want is too murky.

Comment: Thanks alot,turns out that was the problem,so it's fixed. Appreciate it.

Comment: Just a coding tip: since array indexing starts at 0, the usual idiom is to start counting from 0 as well. So the loop would be `for (x1 = 0; x1 < 16; x1++) if (bValue[x1]) bvalue[x1] = false;`.